# dojo.dnd.move node rendering issue

Tags: dojo, drag-and-drop

Dojo has a basic issue, amongst other things... with its dojo.dnd.move class. The issue which you can see here:

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojo/tests/dnd/test_parent_constraints.html

Is that when you click on a node, and start dragging, the node itself jumps. It actually moves its position. This is extremely problematic and I was wondering if anyone has seen this happen before.

I am creating an application that requires the moving of nodes but it needs to be precise and thus can't have the initial jump.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the following highlighted code in Mover.js:

https://github.com/dojo/dojo/blob/master/dnd/Mover.js#L91-92

The odd thing is, based on the comments, it seems like this code is *causing* the very problem it aims to prevent.

That said, if your body has `padding: 0` applied to its style, this code shouldn't affect you.  (You can test it on that test page by running `document.body.style.padding = "0"` in the console before dragging.)

You might want to enter a ticket on the Dojo bug tracker at http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org (or maybe search and see if one has already been entered for it).

Comment: Thank god for stackoverflow! That works perfectly. I have to rewrite my CSS, but that is just fine.